# jQuery clone() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to clone a form input field when user click on Add button everything goes fine, but I have a problem that if I write something in form input field and click Add button, then jQuery will copy that text into new cloned input element also.

You can try a demo: http://jsbin.com/ikebil/2/edit

Steps:

1. Open the link and click render
2. Type something in input field
3. Click on add button it will create a new input field but also copy the text written in the previous one.

Original code: http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

So I need to remove that text which comes if anything is written in the previous element.

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to actually make a copy of the element before it's being populated with any data, and then use that "safe" copy and clone it.
It's faster and safer =>  see [working example](http://jsbin.com/ikebil/4/edit)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `val` to clear out the cloned element. I didn't follow your links (**always** post the code *in the question*), but for instance:

```
var c = field.clone().val("");
```

That clones `field`, then clears the value out of it, and assigns the clone to `c`.

**Update**: I looked at the code, you clone the element but want to change the value on a descendant:

```
// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

// manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
```

Just add `.val("")` to that last line:

```
newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum).val("");
```

Comment: I just refreshed the page to see if someone already answered - I am too slow. :P

Answer (score 1):

`clone` copies all the attributes of element, including its `value`. Just clear it explicitly after cloning if you need that:

```
var newElem = $("#input" + num).clone();
newElem.val("");
```